# Create record of Opportunity record type

Tags: salesforce

I'm a system administrator in my org
I have 3 record types in Opportunity Object.
Out of those 3, I can create record with one record type. But when creating with the other two, the below error comes up:

You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

One more point I want to add here. The record type of which records can be created, those records cannot be edited. Again the same error message comes

Please help in finding the root cause.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Few points: 1. System Admin has all access permissions(C/R/W/View all/Modify all) on Opportunity, 2. OWD of opportunity is Private.

Comment: RE #1: That may be true if the system admin created the new record type in that org, but if the record type was created in a sandbox then deployed into production, without also deploying profiles, then SysAdmin will not have access to the record type.

Answer (score 0):

The new record types need to be made available to your profile.

1. Open the profile in question and scroll down to the "Record Type Settings" section.
2. Locate "Opportunity" in this section, and you should see the name of the record type that you can create and edit.  What you need to do is add the other 2 record types to this field.
3. To do this, click the Edit link in that field and a new screen will appear.
4. Select the record types that you want to make available to the profile, then click the Save button.

I hope this helps.